# Not able to retrieve all the groups using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am very new to Python and have written regular expression where i am able to match the complete pattern but not able to retrieve all the captured matches as shown below. Can someone help me on the below content

**Regular Expression**

```
(?i)(?:sections?|\&\#xA7\;|Treas\.\s*Reg\.)\s*((\d+\.\d+\-\d+(?:\((?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]+|[i v x]+)\))*)(?:\s*(?:and|\,|\,\s*and)\s*)*)+")
```

**Input content to be matched:**

```
1. sections 1.1441-1(e)(4)(iv)(C) and 1.1471-3(c)(6)(iv), 1.576-4(a)(9) and 1.32-12(h)(l)
2. sections 1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23) and 1.11-3(3)(4)(i) , 1.67-9(k)(10) and 1.78-8
```

**Input:**

Q11. Has a Form W--8 that has been completed and signed by a payee, scanned
    into an image or portable document format (PDF), and uploaded to a third--party
    repository been scanned and received electronically by a withholding agent for
    purposes of **sections 1.1441-1(e)(4)(iv)(C) and 1.1471-3(c)(6)(iv), 1.576-4(a)(9) and 1.32-12(h)(l)** if the payee, upon
    request from the withholding agent for a Form W--8 to document its **sections 1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23) and 1.11-3(3)(4)(i) , 1.67-9(k)(10) and 1.78-8** status for
    purposes of chapters 3 and 4, sends the withholding agent an email with a link
    to the third--party repository site that allows the withholding agent to
    download the image or PDF of the form that is stored on the repository for
    such purpose (or the payee otherwise authorizes the withholding agent to
    access the specific form from the third--party repository in a similar manner).

**My Output**

```
['1.32-12(h)(l)','1.78-8']
```

**Desired Output:**

`['1.1441-1(e)(4)(iv)(C)', '1.1471-3(c)(6)(iv)', '1.576-4(a)(9)', '1.32-12(h)(l)', '1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23)', '1.11-3(3)(4)(i)', '1.67-9(k)(10)', '1.78-8']`

**Code:**

```
import re
class Regex:

    def __init__(self,inputtext,regex):
        self.regex=regex
        self.inputtext=inputtext
    def blowCiteQuery(self,inputtext,regex):
        mo=regex.findall(inputtext)
        print(mo)



if __name__ == "__main__":

        text="""Q11. Has a Form W--8 that has been completed and signed by a payee, scanned
into an image or portable document format (PDF), and uploaded to a third--party
repository been scanned and received electronically by a withholding agent for
purposes of sections 1.1441-1(e)(4)(iv)(C) and 1.1471-3(c)(6)(iv), 1.576-4(a)(9) and 1.32-12(h)(l) if the payee, upon
request from the withholding agent for a Form W--8 to document its sections 1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23) and 1.11-3(3)(4)(i) , 1.67-9(k)(10) and 1.78-8 status for
purposes of chapters 3 and 4, sends the withholding agent an email with a link
to the third--party repository site that allows the withholding agent to
download the image or PDF of the form that is stored on the repository for
such purpose (or the payee otherwise authorizes the withholding agent to
access the specific form from the third--party repository in a similar manner)."""

        regex=re.compile("(?i)(?:sections?|\&\#xA7\;|Treas\.\s*Reg\.)\s*((\d+\.\d+\-\d+(?:\((?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]+|[i v x]+)\))*)(?:\s*(?:and|\,|\,\s*and)\s*)*)+")
        treglinkval=Regex(text,regex)
        treglinkval.blowCiteQuery(text,regex)
```

Comment: Like [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/qJ5oQ2/1) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
sections\ 
(?P<section1>[-.\w()]+)
\ and\ 
(?P<section2>[-.\w()]+)
(?P<optional>
    (?:,\ [-.\w()]+)+
)?
```

And use `re.finditer()` afterwards, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qJ5oQ2/2).
This captures comma separated groups in the group "optional", you'll need to split these by comma programmatically.

```
import re
rx = re.compile("""
sections\ 
(?P<section1>[-.\w()]+)
\ and\ 
(?P<section2>[-.\w()]+)
(?P<optional>
    (?:,\ [-.\w()]+)+
)?""", re.VERBOSE)

sections = [(m.group('section1'), m.group('section2')) for m in rx.finditer(your_text_here)]
print sections
# [('1.1441-1(e)(4)(iv)(C)', '1.1471-3(c)(6)(iv)'), ('1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23)', '1.11-3(3)(4)(i)')]
```

A complete [**demo can be found on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/BBiCCM).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what if you have more than two values which contains sections 1.44-3(a)(g) and 2.34-6(k)(6) , 6.39-5(0)(g) and so on ?

Comment: @Praveen: You example did not have these cases, please edit your question and provide some.

Comment: Question updated. As per my regex you can see there is a repeating capture and i am able to get get only last captures. So how can we solve this particular issue?

Comment: @Praveen: See updated answer. With this kind of repeating pattern, you can only capture the optional group as a whole, not the single parts.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `(?i)` and the regex works for me on your sample... You are also using non-capturing groups, and regex won't give you separate groups for repeating the same capture group, it will just keep the last one, which is why you're seeing it output as just two copies of the same thing.

Personally, I'd just grab the whole matches, and do something like:

```
result = []
for match in matches:
    pieces = match.split(' ')
    result.append((pieces[1], pieces[3]))
return result
```

which gives

`('1.1441-1(e)(12)(i)(23)', '1.11-3(3)(4)(i)')`
for each match.